# How do you use libpqxx stream_to table or raw_table

Tags: c++17, libpqxx

I'm using libpqxx version 7.7.0. I want to use the stream_to features. When I follow the examples found on https://libpqxx.readthedocs.io/en/7.7.0/a01429.html I get a warning saying that the stream_to function is deprecated and I should be using table or raw_table. Although I'm really struggling to get those static functions to work, and I can't find any examples anywhere of how they are used. I've read the docs for the functions found at https://libpqxx.readthedocs.io/en/7.7.0/a01176.html#a34d7ca93963c0b5733a9ebcc10f2429b. Has anybody figured how to use that functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to use the raw_table function. It appeared to be much simpler than the table command.

```
std::vector<std::tuple<float, std::string>> data = testData();
pqxx::work transaction{ conn };
pqxx::stream_to stream = pqxx::stream_to::raw_table(transaction, "<schema>.<table>", "<col1>, <col2>,...");
for (auto &tuple : data) {
   stream << tuple;
}
stream.complete();
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's @Neza's example but adjusted to use [pqxx::stream_to::table](https://libpqxx.readthedocs.io/en/7.7.0/a01176.html#a34d7ca93963c0b5733a9ebcc10f2429b):

```c++
pqxx::work transaction{ conn };
pqxx::stream_to stream = pqxx::stream_to::table(transaction, {"schema","table"}, {"col1", "col2"});
for (auto &tuple : data) {
   stream << tuple;
}
stream.complete();
transaction.commit();
```

The second parameter to `pqxx::stream_to::table` is [table_path](https://libpqxx.readthedocs.io/en/7.7.0/a00253.html#a7f913d1e427c805856ac303db75c1e57) and both it and the third parameter are [initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) of string.