# libpqxx stream_to with std::vector

Tags: c++, postgresql, c++17, stdtuple, libpqxx

I use prepared statement to save 1 entity to database

```
_connection.prepare("save", "INSERT INTO public.table (col1, col2, col3)  VALUES ($1, $2, $3)");
```

Then in my Save function I do:

```
void DBRepository::Save(const DBEntity &entity)
{
    pqxx::work w(_connection);

    try
    {
        w.exec_prepared("save",
                        entity.col1(),
                        entity.col2(),
                        entity.col3());
        w.commit();
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

I want to use use lipqxx::stream_to utility in a bulk insert function

```
void DBRepository::BulkInsert(const std::vector<DBEntity>) { ... }
```

as stated in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71928457/how-do-you-use-libpqxx-stream-to-table-or-raw-table/) i get a deprecated warning if i use the sample code in the libpqxx documentation.

For the accepted answer, how can I convert to my data into convenient tuple and use my prepared statement to avoid escaping ?